# 19.10: There is no sound on Asus Zenbook UX534

Tags: sound, kernel, alsa, asus

I have the problem with sound on subject.

- OS: Ubuntu 19.10
- Kernel:  5.3.0-41-generic #33-Ubuntu

**Alsa details:** http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=9f087f5038e450cf77cdf21d21f86af763626d78

**Bugs:**

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206289
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850439

Does anybody has workaround or solution about this critical issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Since when do you have this problem?
For me the problem with no sound started with the 5.3.0-41 kernel.
Booting with the older 5.3.0-40 kernel solves my problem.

Comment: I've tried it with 5.3.0-30, 5.3.0-40 etc. Problem exist

Answer (score 0):

Actually on one of the links in the question there is an answer now (by [Erikas](https://launchpad.net/~erikmnkl)):

> 1. Disable all commands that are performed on boot.
> 2. Reboot laptop - sound is not working
> 3. Apply only these manually:
>
>    ```bsh
>    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
>    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
>    ```
> 4. Listen to some audio and realize if sound sounds OK or if some frequencies are distorted.
> 5. Reboot
> 6. Apply only these manually:
>
>    ```bsh
>    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
>    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
>    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
>    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
>    ```

For me the first two commands were enough and I didn't reboot or something before applying them.

Here is the full answer: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850439/comments/170